# Antimatter Majorana and DIrac

Tags: dirac-equation, antimatter, majorana-fermions

i have a question , how did Dirac derive the existence of antimmater from his equation ??

$$i \hbar \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi - m c \psi = 0$$

and why for the Majorana equation predicts the existence of massive particles which are their own anti- particles ?

the majorana equation is real valued only ?  $$ i \, {\partial\!\!\!\big /} \psi - m\, \psi_c = 0~ $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirac *did not* originally predict antimatter. He thought that the positive charged particle should be the *proton*. That  the theory  forced it to have the same mass of the electron was a seen as a failure of his equation. It was only after the experimental discovery of antimatter that the equation was understood to be correctly describing the positron.